# Prefixing string from Android Database

Tags: android

I am trying to display information from a database in my android app. However, I would like it prefixed with the character €. Is that possible?

My Current code:

```
String[] from = new String[]{savingDB.KEY_DATE};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.date};
```

What I tried:

```
String[] from = new String[]{"€" + savingDB.KEY_DATE};

int[] to = new int[]{R.id.date};
```

Comment: Why are you prefixing a date with the currency symbol for the Euro?

Comment: was just an example. I am not prefixing it to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna have to do something custom. There are at least a couple of alternatives. If you're using a SimpleCursorAdapter the simplest is to just override the `bindView()` method and forcefully set the value on the view that you want. You can look at the [SimpleCursorAdapter code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View,android.content.Context,android.database.Cursor%29) to get an idea of what you have to do. Boils down to retrieving your column from the Cursor, finding the view you want to set and calling `view.setText("$" + stringFromCursor);`

Alternatively, you can roll your own Cursor and instead of getting just the `savingDB.KEY_DATE` column from the database, you query the database using a concatenation, like: `"select '€' || " + savingDB.KEY_DATE + " from yourtable". Something like that.

Comment: Thanks for that. Since there was no standard way, I ended up just created a new textview for it with no padding and it worked. Thanks!